# Matplotlib does not plot curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

`plt.show()`, displays a window, but there's no curve on it.

**My code:**

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [4]: Lm=0

In [5]: for angle in np.arange(0.0,90.0,0.1):

   ...:     theta = angle*math.pi/180

   ...:     L=0.25*(math.cos(theta))*(5*math.sin(theta)+math.sqrt(25*math.sin(theta)*math.sin(theta)+80))

   ...:     print(L,"\t",angle)

   ...:     if L>Lm:

   ...:         Lm=L

   ...:


In [6]: plt.figure(1)

Out[6]: <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x284e5014208>

In [7]: for angle in np.arange(0.0,90.0,0.1):

   ...:     celta = angle*math.pi/180

   ...:     L=0.25*(math.cos(theta))*(5*math.sin(theta)+math.sqrt(25*math.sin(theta)*math.sin(theta)+80))

   ...:     plt.figure(1)

   ...:     plt.plot(angle,L)

   ...:

In [8]: plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: With every call of `plt.plot`, a `Lines` object is added to the `Figure` instance. A `Lines` object tries to make lines between the points given in order (linear interpolation). Now the problem is that to make a line one needs at least two points, but with every single call of `plt.plot` you create a `Lines` object with only one point. That is why you don't see anything. Use NumPy's universal functions `sin` and `cos` instead and let them work with arrays instead.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the second calculation of `L` is exactly the same as the first one (except that you always use the same value of `theta`, which I guess is not what you're trying to achieve in the second loop). Also you don't use `celta` at all. We're just going to kick that out. `Lm` is not used at all, so I'm also gonna kick that out too, but from what I see you can just calculate `Lm` afterwards with `np.max(L)`.

What is left is the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

angles = np.arange(0.0, 90.0, 0.1)
theta = angles * np.pi / 180
L = 0.25 * np.cos(theta) * (5*np.sin(theta) +
                            np.sqrt(25*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(theta) + 80))
plt.plot(angles, L)
plt.show()
```

Now, you have only one call of `plt.plot` which creates a `Lines` instance with a lot of points and you can see a plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really corrected my mistakes and told me the convenient way.